# Saving dynamically created buttons in android

Tags: java, android

I have a "creator button" in my action bar that, when pressed, creates other buttons in my main activity. Every time this button is pressed, a new button is created in my main activity, creating a list of buttons.

The buttons that are created are each associated with a custom object. When pressed, the buttons pass their associated object to a method and open a new fragment.

**Question:**

My question is, how can I save all of these buttons/associated objects that the user creates?

**Attempt at solution:**

I tried to store the buttons/objects in a hashmap, writing an internal wrapper class containing the hashmap and then using Gson to convert to/from JSON, but when I try to convert back from JSON, Gson.fromJson(jsonString) returns null (I have a suspicion this is because I am trying to store buttons).

Here is some of the code for my attempted solution:

```
public void saveButtonsMap() {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    MapWrapper wrapper = new MapWrapper();
    wrapper.setMap(buttonsMap);
    String serializedMap = gson.toJson(buttonsMap);

    Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putString(BUTTONS_MAP, serializedMap);
    editor.commit();
}

public void restoreButtonsMap() {
    String mapString = prefs.getString(BUTTONS_MAP, "");

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    if(!mapString.isEmpty()) {
        MapWrapper wrapper = gson.fromJson(mapString, MapWrapper.class); // this is returning null
        buttonsMap = wrapper.getMap();
    }
    else {
        buttonsMap = new HashMap<Button, CustomObject>();
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Rather than saving button just save the object that represent the button as in the text and the fragment tag. So in onCreate you can check if the json string is present in cache, get it and parse it through gson and restore the buttons accordingly.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing, thanks.